# windows Power shell's shortcut keys not working

Tags: windows, powershell-4.0

My windows Power shell's debug shortcuts are stopped working. For toggle break point,if I press F9 it opens Windows search window! F11 for step into is not working. (all the debug shortcuts). I use windows 7 and power shell version 5.1.15509. I restored the default setting of PS. Still not working.

Comment: One thing I just noticed is it is giving problem when I connect via vpn, but not all the time.

Comment: Found the fix I think.I will update it below.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. This is a dell laptop and when I take it out of the docking station I need to press the 'Fn' key +shortcut function keys like F9, F11 etc. So for F9  to toggle break point ,I need to press Fn + F9.